# Doesn't Google Apps Script support @typedef in library?

Tags: google-apps-script, jsdoc

If `@typedef` is described in a library it seems that autocomplete doesn't work as expected on a file which imports library; object type is turned into any. Is there any solution to tell object's structure to another script?

Please note that I don't want to use non-gas technique like TypeScript. Thanks.

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} myVegetable
 * @property {string} name
 * @property {number} price
 */
/** @type {myVegetable} */
var myVegetable = { name: "carrot", price: 1 };
```

[image]

img1 - `@typedef` works as expected in same file.

[image]

img2 - type `myVegetable` is turned into any on file which imports library.

Comment: Relevant [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36754997)

Answer (score -1):

### GAS Alone Does Not Support Typescript

Google Apps Script (GAS) does not support typescript without adding additional tools. Based on the article [Develop Apps Script using TypeScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/typescript), you may incorporate typescript in GAS with `clasp`. However, this requires you to install the following to enable your local development environment:

1. Node and npm
2. Clasp
3. Type definitions for Apps Script
4. Visual Studio Code (for TypeScript IDE autocompletion)

### References:

For further details, you may view the following links:

1. [Develop Apps Script using TypeScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/typescript)
2. [Command Line Interface using clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp)

Comment: May I ask whether you needed the library with @typedef to be compatible with GAS or you just needed a fix to the autocomplete bug? It was in my understanding that you needed to use the library with typescript format that's why I based my answer on the Develop Apps Script using TypeScript article by Google as a workaround.